# Listview HasUnEvenRows Not working

Tags: c#, ios, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a listview with three different cell contents inside only one of it shows on that cell through binding checks. I did not set the height of the view cell but set the vertical option of its stack layout child to 'fill'. Now, this works on android but mysteriously not on iOs. I already set the hasuneven rows to true but upon tapping each cell, I noticed that the height is the same. I'll show the xaml code and the item source code:

```
   <ListView
        x:Name = "lvConversations"
        VerticalOptions = "FillAndExpand"
        HorizontalOptions = "FillAndExpand"
        IsGroupingEnabled = "false"
        SeparatorVisibility = "None"
        HasUnevenRows = "true"
        ItemSelected = "messageSelected"
        BackgroundColor = "#F8F8F8"
        >

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:ScaledViewCell>
                <local:ScaledStackLayout
                    VerticalOptions = "Fill"
                    HorizontalOptions = "FillAndExpand"
                    Orientation = "Vertical"
                    Spacing = "0">

                    <local:ScaledStackLayout
                        VerticalOptions = "Fill"
                        HorizontalOptions = "FillAndExpand"
                        Orientation = "Vertical"
                        Spacing = "0"
                        IsVisible = "{Binding isGroupHeader, Converter = {StaticResource inverter}}"
                        BackgroundColor = "Transparent">

                        <!-- OUTGOING -->
                            <local:ScaledStackLayout
                                HorizontalOptions = "FillAndExpand" Orientation = "Horizontal"
                                IsVisible = "{Binding isOutgoing}">


                                    <local:ScaledStackLayout
                                        VerticalOptions = "Fill"
                                        HorizontalOptions = "EndAndExpand"
                                        BackgroundColor = "Transparent"
                                        Orientation = "Vertical"
                                        Margin = "21,14,15,0"
                                        Spacing = "0">

                                        <local:ScaledStackLayout
                                            Orientation = "Horizontal"
                                            VerticalOptions = "Fill"
                                            HorizontalOptions = "EndAndExpand"
                                            Spacing = "0"
                                            >
                                            <local:CorneredView
                                                CornerRadius = "15"
                                                BackgroundColor = "#d3eaf6"
                                                VerticalOptions = "Fill"
                                                HorizontalOptions = "End"
                                                >
                                                <Label 
                                                    VerticalOptions = "Fill"
                                                    HorizontalOptions = "Fill"
                                                    Text = "{Binding message}"
                                                    FontSize = "10"
                                                    TextColor = "Black"
                                                    Margin = "7,10,7,10"
                                                    LineBreakMode = "WordWrap"
                                                />

                                            </local:CorneredView>
                                            <Image
                                                Margin = "0,11,7,0"
                                                Source = "ic_msg_arrow_outgoing"
                                                WidthRequest = "5"
                                                HeightRequest = "10"
                                                Aspect = "AspectFit"
                                                BackgroundColor = "Transparent"
                                                VerticalOptions = "Start"
                                                />
                                            <ffimageloading:CachedImage
                                                WidthRequest = "37"
                                                HeightRequest = "37"
                                                BackgroundColor = "Transparent"
                                                VerticalOptions = "Start"
                                                Aspect = "AspectFill"
                                                Source = "{Binding sender.imageUrl}"
                                                DownsampleToViewSize =  "true"
                                                DownsampleUseDipUnits = "true"
                                                >

                                                <ffimageloading:CachedImage.Transformations>
                                                <fftransformations:CircleTransformation>
                                                    <x:Arguments>
                                                      <x:Double>2</x:Double>
                                                      <x:String>#FF8A07</x:String>
                                                    </x:Arguments>
                                                </fftransformations:CircleTransformation>
                                                </ffimageloading:CachedImage.Transformations>

                                        </ffimageloading:CachedImage>

                                        </local:ScaledStackLayout>

                                        <Label
                                            Margin = "0,3,0,0"
                                            VerticalOptions = "Center"
                                            HorizontalOptions = "Start"
                                            Text = "{Binding formattedDateSent}"
                                            HeightRequest = "10"
                                            FontSize = "8"
                                            TextColor = "#4D212121"/>
                                    </local:ScaledStackLayout>


                            </local:ScaledStackLayout>

                        <!--INCOMING-->
                        <local:ScaledStackLayout
                            WidthRequest = "284"
                            VerticalOptions = "Fill"
                            BackgroundColor = "Transparent"
                            Orientation = "Vertical"
                            Margin = "15,14,21,0"
                            Spacing = "0"
                            IsVisible = "{Binding isOutgoing, Converter = {StaticResource inverter}}">

                            <local:ScaledStackLayout
                                Orientation = "Horizontal"
                                WidthRequest = "284"
                                VerticalOptions = "Fill"
                                Spacing = "0"
                                >
                                <ffimageloading:CachedImage
                                    WidthRequest = "37"
                                    HeightRequest = "37"
                                    BackgroundColor = "Transparent"
                                    VerticalOptions = "Start"
                                    Aspect = "AspectFill"
                                    Source = "{Binding sender.imageUrl}"
                                    DownsampleToViewSize =  "true"
                                    DownsampleUseDipUnits = "true"
                                    >
                                    <ffimageloading:CachedImage.Transformations>
                                        <fftransformations:CircleTransformation>
                                            <x:Arguments>
                                              <x:Double>2</x:Double>
                                              <x:String>#FF8A07</x:String>
                                            </x:Arguments>
                                        </fftransformations:CircleTransformation>
                                    </ffimageloading:CachedImage.Transformations>
                                </ffimageloading:CachedImage>

                                <Image
                                    Margin = "7,15,0,0"
                                    Source = "ic_msg_arrow_incoming"
                                    WidthRequest = "5"
                                    HeightRequest = "10"
                                    Aspect = "AspectFit"
                                    BackgroundColor = "Transparent"
                                    VerticalOptions = "Start"

                                    />
                                <local:CorneredView
                                    WidthRequest = "235"
                                    VerticalOptions = "Fill"
                                    CornerRadius = "15"
                                    BackgroundColor = "#ECECEC"
                                    IsClippedToBounds = "true"
                                    >
                                    <Label 
                                        VerticalOptions = "Fill"
                                        HorizontalOptions = "FillAndExpand"
                                        Text = "{Binding message}"
                                        FontSize = "10"
                                        TextColor = "Black"
                                        Margin = "7,10,7,10"
                                        LineBreakMode = "WordWrap"
                                    />

                                </local:CorneredView>
                            </local:ScaledStackLayout>

                            <Label
                                Margin = "0,3,0,0"
                                VerticalOptions = "Center"
                                HorizontalOptions = "End"
                                Text = "{Binding formattedDateSent}"
                                HeightRequest = "10"
                                FontSize = "8"
                                TextColor = "#4D212121"/>

                        </local:ScaledStackLayout>

                    </local:ScaledStackLayout>
                    <!--Message Group-->
                    <local:ScaledStackLayout
                        Margin = "0"
                        Padding = "0"
                        Spacing = "0"
                        Orientation = "Vertical"
                        VerticalOptions = "Fill"
                        IsVisible = "{Binding isGroupHeader}"
                        BackgroundColor = "Transparent"
                        >
                        <!--label and button-->
                        <local:ScaledStackLayout
                            Margin = "9,0,9,0"
                            HeightRequest = "19"
                            Orientation = "Horizontal"
                            Padding = "0,5,7,0"
                            BackgroundColor = "Transparent">

                            <Label 
                                Text = "{Binding groupHeaderTitle}"
                                HorizontalOptions = "FillAndExpand"
                                HeightRequest = "8"
                                FontSize = "8"
                                TextColor = "#212121"
                                VerticalTextAlignment = "Center"
                                HorizontalTextAlignment = "Center"
                                BackgroundColor = "Transparent"/>

                        </local:ScaledStackLayout>

                        <BoxView
                            Margin = "9,0,9,0"
                            HorizontalOptions = "FillAndExpand"
                            HeightRequest = "1"
                            BackgroundColor = "#4D212121"/>


                    </local:ScaledStackLayout>

                    </local:ScaledStackLayout>
                </local:ScaledViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>
```

I will also attach the photos on both android and iOs
 [image: Andrioid Page]
  [image: iOs Page]

As you can see, the cells are overlapping.

The code I used to populate the listview is this:

```
public void OnSuccess(JObject response, BaseAPI caller)
{
    if (Constants.isDebug)
    {

        JObject json = TestData.getTestData("conversation_messages_listed.json");
        response = json;
    }



    ObservableCollection<Message> arrMessages = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Message>>(response["messages"].ToString(), new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
        MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore
    });

    lvConversations.ItemsSource = arrMessages;
}
```

Please help, I'm new to xamarin.

Comment: Hard to tell without the code of ScaledStackLayout, ScaledViewCell  and possibly CorneredView,  If you want to provide the sample to reproduce the problem it might speed up the solution.

Comment: Those are just simple subclass of Stacklayout, viewcell and frame. Not much changes than the superclass except that they scale their size depending on the device screen dimensions. I used it on other pages of the app so im pretty sure its not on one of those that causes the problem.

Comment: I need to write a lot of code to reproduce (message class, inveter, etc). If you still need help please provide sample project.

Answer (score 4):

HasUnevenRows won't work by default on iOS. See this [comment on a bug report](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=22535#c11):

> iOS does not support automatically sizing row cells, you must set a ListView.RowHeight or a Cell.Height. Unfortunately, we did not specifically disable this from working on Android or Windows Phone (where it just works without our intervention), and it has lead some to believe that iOS is broken in this respect.
>
> Unfortunately this is a limitation of the iOS platform and therefore is the intended behavior.

It may also be helpful to look over the [docs for HasUnevenRows property](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.ListView.HasUnevenRows/#Remarks).

> When the app developer sets the ListView.HasUnevenRows property to true, the behavior of the list view still depends on the ListView.RowHeight property. First, if the developer either does not set the ListView.RowHeight property or sets it to -1, list view items are autosized to fit their contents. This is the desired behavior and the intended use case for a ListView.HasUnevenRows value of true, as noted above. Second, if the developer sets the ListView.RowHeight property to 0 or to a negative value other than -1, then all rows in the ListView will, irrespective of the height of their content, have the default height for the system. Third, and finally, if the developer sets ListView.RowHeight to a positive value, then all rows in the ListView will, irrespective of the height of their content, be as tall as ListView.RowHeight, as if ListView.HasUnevenRows had been set to false.

Answer (score 0):

When clicked, you can call `ForceUpdateSize()`, which fixes the issue:

```
var clicked = (StackLayout)sender;
            ((ViewCell)((Grid)((StackLayout)((PancakeView)((StackLayout)clicked.Parent).Parent).Parent).Parent).Parent).ForceUpdateSize();
```